# Simulating a variable mutual inductance model

Tags: inductor, simulation, simulink, mutual-inductance

Can we simulate a time varying mutual inductance in Matlab Simulink (or any other simulation tool).

Matlab Simulink has [a variable inductor](https://se.mathworks.com/help/physmod/elec/ref/variableinductor.html), but I could not find not mutual inductor.

Comment: Well I’m sure you could model one in simulink with the correct parameters using math blocks

Comment: A mutual inductor is another name for a transformer. Check out the transformer block. https://au.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/lineartransformer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (or any other simulation tool)

In LTspice you have the behavioural inductor. The expression is a function of `x`, `Flux=f(x)`, where `x` has a special significance denoting the derivative of the current through the inductor. See more about it in the manual. Don't forget that the expression needs integrating beforehand. For example, say you need the inductance to vary as \$-2x^3+3x^2+1\$. After integration you get \$-\frac{x^4}{2}+x^3+x\$, and that's what you need to use. Also don't forget that, in LTspice, `**` is used to mean exponentiation, instead of `^`:

[image: flux]

The test setup has a current source with a unit current ramp, which translates into the voltage across the inductor being the actual inductance -- `V(n001)` in the picture (the only node, actually). You should take care that, due to the derivative, sharp discontinuities may appear (see the sharp rise at time t=0), it's up to you to handle those, LTspice will gladly calculate anything you throw at it.

Comment: Thanks, However, LTSpice says "mutual inductance aren't supported between arbitrary inductors"!

Comment: @Pojj You can use behavioural inductors, or even the Chan core, to make a transformer. See the `Examples` folder under your LTspice installation -- `NonLinearTransformer.asc`, and [this ltwiki page](http://ltwiki.org/?title=Transformers) on tips how to build one.

Comment: Perfect! let me digest it slowly...