# How to model an inductor using a behavioural voltage source in LTspice (to get time-dependent inductors)?

Tags: inductor, ltspice, spice

I am trying to make a time-dependent inductor in LTspice, but it is not as easy as for resistors which allow values directly depending on 'time'. I tried using the characteristic equation of an inductor and a behavioural voltage source in the simplest circuit I could think of as follows, but it does not work (the current reaches 10^37A... How could I achieve this?
[image]

The current through R6 goes left to right, but I tried adding a negative sign to the V equation anyway, just in case (even if it would not make sense to me).

---

### Solution (thanks to "a concerned citizen")

[image]

Which corresponds to the function L(t)=L0*(1+(K*sin(wt))^2), in a series RL test circuit excited by a constant sine wave.

Comment: There has been some discussion of this in the LTspice mailing list. As I recall it's a bit complex.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/393905/simulating-a-variable-mutual-inductance-model)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/393905/simulating-a-variable-mutual-inductance-model) deals with the builtin behavioural inductor from LTspice. In addition, here's another way of doing it, compared with the linked version:

[image: test]

`V1` generates a `1 V / 1 s` ramp which, through the VCCSs `G1`and `G2`, becomes a unity \$\frac{\mathrm{d}i}{\mathrm{d}t}\$. Since \$v=L\frac{\mathrm{d}i}{\mathrm{d}t}\$ it follows that \$v=L\$, that is, the inductance can be read in Volts.

The two cases shown are with traditional SPICE elements, `L`, `F`, and `B` (upper side), and with the builtin behavioural inductor (lower side). The function that dynamically modifies the inductors is (randomly) chosen to be of the form \$\frac{1}{1+f(t)}\$.

For the 1st case, `F1` takes the current though `B1` and feeds it into `L1`, and the voltage that forms across it is used as a feedback for `B1`. Adding any other expression (not a constant) besides `V(L)` would transform this into a variable inductor. Here, `B1` has the expression `V(L)/(1 + I(G2))`, where `I(G2)` is \$f(t)\$. Note that LTspice discourages using "*instantaneous feedback*" (see the help on B-sources for more), so I'm using `I(G2)` instead of `I(B1)` in the behavioural expression.

For the 2nd case, `x` has the special meaning of the current though the inductor which, as shown in the other linked answer, is internally differentiated. Thus, the function of `x` first needs to be integrated:

$$\int{\frac{1}{1+f(t)}\mathrm{d}t}=\log\left(1+f(t)\right)$$

`x` takes the place of \$f(t)\$ and the expression becomes what you see. Note that, for this particular case, the input voltage must not go below `-1 V`, for obvious reasons. The plots show the voltages across the two variable inductors, with `V(1)` slightly shifted for better viewing, otherwise they would completely overlap. `V(test)` from `B2` is the reference equation, also shifted, showing the exactness of the match.

---

\$\sin^2x\$ varies between 0 and 1, which means you'll have times when your inductance will be zero; that's asking for trouble. It looks like you want to model the coupling inside a motor, so a better solution would be \$1+\sin^2x\$, and even better \$1-\mathrm{K}+\sin^2x\$. Of course, I am just speculating, it's up to you to know better.

That said, there's nothing stopping you from using the alternative method (the more involved one), and also `x` is not mandatory, it's just there as a helping notation. Internally, LTspice will apply partial derivatives to all the variables used.

Supposing you can live with \$1+\sin^2x\$, here's a rework of the above:

[image: alt]

Just as before, `V(test)` outputs the original time-varying formula (described in the green-text comment), while `V(1)` (shifted by `5 m`) and `V(2)` (shifted by `10 m`) are the resulting variable inductances.

---

And here is a way to use the two inductors in a random series RLC circuit:

[image: use]

1) The SPICE way. The solid rectangle is the "engine" for the variable inductor. It is to be used together with `B1`, that is `B1 + F1 + L1` form an inductor, whose "interface" to the world is `B1`, inside the dotted rectangle. The voltage that appears at `B1`'s pins is the voltage of the equivalent inductor. `F1 + L1` can be placed anywhere in the circuit, their only connection to `B1` is behind the scenes.

2) The LTspice way. It's really this simple: simply place the inductor in the circuit. As above, the dotted rectangle marks the element to use.

Both circuits are identical in terms of results: the same source (`1 V / 50 Hz`), the same R (10 Ω) and C (10μF), and the same equivalent variable inductance. The currents and voltages are plotted, one slightly shifted than the other to avoid complete overlapping.

---

As conclusions:

- the generic SPICE method (upper) is more involved, but it has the advantage that you don't need to calculate the integral of the expression. As can be seen, `B1` has the exact formula as its expression. The builtin behavioural inductor requires an integral of the formula, but it's simpler.
- both of them allow for external sources of control. The generic one directly specified, while the behavioural one needs it integrated beforehand.
- both of them deal with derivatives, internally or otherwise, so noise considerations should not be discarded.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's very interesting (+1). I don't see how I can apply this though, since I would like the inductor to vary with respect to time and not current: I would like to have L(t)=L0*[K*sin(w*t)]² - but integrating this yields L0*K²*(t/2-sin(2*w*t)/(4*w)). No x... Any idea?

Comment: I've updated my answer, thank you for the +1. Judging by your reputation, you already know this, but if you think this answers your question, be sure to mark it down so that others, in the furure, searching for similar problems, will know that this question has an accepted answer.

Comment: I'm very sorry but even with your update, both solutions either I do not understand, or I cannot apply: a) in solution 1, I don't get how F1 and B1 do not create an infinite loop (or what F1 and L do actually) ; b) I understand solution 2 (the current through L2 is equal in value to time so we can use the flux expression subsituting time with current) but I do not know how to use the varying inductor in the simple circuit attached in my post (same thing for solution 1 in fact) ; c) Why is the inductance varying at 100Hz instead of 50Hz? I always accept answers so rest assured I will :) Thanks!

Comment: a) You need to brush up on some SPICE usage. here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTwsNkd21pc) about variable capacitors, but at the end it has inductors (don't skip too much), and [this](https://ultimateelectronicsbook.com/dependent-sources/) is a link for CCVS and CCCS and how they work. b) You simply use the inductor (`B1` or `L2`) in the circuit as you would a normal inductor. (I'll update my answer with an example for this). c) I only used your formula, which is a function of \$\sin^2x=\frac{1-\cos2x}{2}\$ (note the \$2x\$). It's why the integral has \$\sin\$, not \$\cos\$.

Comment: a) Thanks, I'm going to work on that. b) Thanks for the confirmation, I updated my original post with the solution and accepted your answer :) I don't see how solution 2 can work this way (the flux being the integral of the current, which is in your application example definitely not the time), so I adapted your example of solution 1 (I corrected I(R2) with the time, otherwise I don't see how it can represent my formula) and it looks consistent. c) Gee, my bad - forgot about the square. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Great link to the video on variable caps and inductors, it was quite straightforward in the end when the multiplication on both sides of the characteristic equation showed up. See you around on SE!