# How to change input impedance electronically?

Tags: resistors, inductor

I need to simulate a wire loop in presence of a metal(usually iron) near it and without the metal.
the resistance of the wire is constant (suppose R=20ohm) but the inductance of it changes; The inductance drops when the iron is near. L1=100uH in presence of metal and L2=560uH in absence of it.

I want to remove this loop and use fixed inductors and resistors and a push button to simulate the presence of the metal.

Any Idea that can help?

Comment: What you need is to model the *variation* of the inductance in the presence of the iron. That's up to you to determine with pen and paper. Using the equivalent of a push button will, most probably, not give the answers you seek. Welcome to the site.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen thanks, I have determined the variation 100uH and 560uH. but  I need a circuit that changes between these two values.

Comment: Would [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/393905/95619) help? It's for LTspice, only, but there is a [SPICE-compatible](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/499278/95619) way to do it.