# LTSpice - Inductance simulation

Tags: ltspice, inductance

Welcome back on this subject :

I would like to simulate an inductance which varies linearly in function of the current which flows through it. Suppose :
$$L(t) = I_{L}(t)$$
In the simulation for simplicity I used a current source which has a slope of current equal to :
$$\frac{dI_{L}(t)}{dt} = 1$$
So :
$$U_{L}(t) = L(t)\frac{dI_{L}(t)}{dt} = L(t) = I_{L}(t)$$

Finally the expression of the Flux for L should be :
$$Flux(t) = x^2/2$$

Refere to this link for the expression of the flux : [LTspice - Simulation of a variable inductance](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/538466/ltspice-simulation-of-a-variable-inductance/538805?noredirect=1#comment1396808_538805)

So here is the simulation :
[image]

And here are the result :
[image]

What is weird to me is that I have to add a minus sign in the expression of the flux of the inductance. Why ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you certain that the direction you assumed for the inductor current is the same as the direction that LTspice assumes?

Comment: You mean what is the sign of "x" ? I assume "x" has the same sign that I(L2)

Comment: Looking at the graphs of voltage and current, congratulations on creating a 1 ohm resistor and dissipating 10 MW in R1.

Comment: Thank you for your point :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inductors have phase in LTspice.  If you rotate the inductor 180°, you will no longer need to multiply by -1.

It can also be helpful to use the inductor symbol with a phasing dot.  Here is the correct orientation that will remove the need for multiplying by -1:

[image]

Comment: You are right ! Thank you :) Nevertheless I have to put the phasing dot in the reverse direction with repest to you phasing dot

Answer (score -1):

I can only assume that the convention of flux is just defined like that. It should not really matter either, as depending on how you are coiling your inductor (left-hand or right-hand coil), the effect of any externally defined flux inverts. However, since you are using a square, you are losing that "direction", so you have to worry about something that you usually don't really need to worry about.

If you want a more "generic" solution, replace the flux expression with:

$$Flux = sgn(x)*(x**2)/2$$

This makes it irrespective of the inductor polarity again.